# Return the count of a selected string from dropdown in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a column which takes input from a List (A, B, C, D)
How to obtain the number of times that 'A' has been selected in this column?

Comment: `COUTIF()` will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your data is in column A.

It has many rows and there are only four different types of entries, like this:

[image]

There are several ways you can count how many apples or bananas are in the list.

**Option 1 - a formula**
To prepare for that, create a list of the four fruit types in cells C1 to C4, with apples, bananas, oranges and cherries as the values. Then in D1 enter the formula

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,C1)
```

Copy the formula down. The result should look like this:

[image]

**Option 2 - Pivot table**

Click anywhere within column a, then click Insert > Pivot Table. Drag the data field into the row area and drag the data field again into the Values area. The result will look like this:

[image]

If you have any questions about the particular aspects of these suggestions, please post in Superuser.com. Stackoverflow.com is really meant for programming questions, not basic software usage.